# Get a feature properties for the layer which has been clicked in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am working on OpenLayers 3 with Geoserver, I have four vector layers, I am using `singleclick` event to get properties for each feature and show them in a popup window.

Now my problem that when i click on a feature from the highest layer i get all properties from all layers which are lower, I used `forEachFeatureAtPixel` but i don't know how to specify it for each layer!

Here is my code:

```
var OpenMeters = function (evt) {
content.innerHTML = "";
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature, layer) {
        if (feature) {
            var coord = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel);
            var objeto = feature.getProperties(),propiedades;
            for (propiedades in objeto)
            {
              content.innerHTML += '<b>' + propiedades + '</b> : <i><b>'+ objeto[propiedades]+'</b></i><br />';
            }
            overlay.setPosition(coord);
        } else {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        }
    });
};

map.on('singleclick', OpenMeters);

var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
map.addInteraction(select);
```

How can i specify `singleclick` event for each layer ?
Any help ?

Comment: At least for me, it's not clear what you want. Maybe you want a layer filter? See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127072/50718.

Comment: I saw this and tried it .. but it gives me properties just for the layer which i have put in the filter and if i click on another layer it doesn't give any properties.
In the same pixel which i click i have three features under each other what i want when i click on a feature from the highest layer to give me properties for this feature just in this layer and not all preporties for the features in the pixel, is it clear now ?

Comment: Not really. Maybe you put this on a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify a single click for each layer but according to the [api doc of forEachFeatureAtPixel function](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) :

```
Returns:

Callback result, i.e. the return value of last callback execution, or the first truthy callback return value.
```

So if your return a value on the first call of the callback you will get the first feature you hit:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
  return feature;    
});
if (feature) {
  var coord = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel);
  var objeto = feature.getProperties(),propiedades;
  for (propiedades in objeto) {
    content.innerHTML += '<b>' + propiedades + '</b> : <i><b>'+ objeto[propiedades]+'</b></i><br />';
    }
    overlay.setPosition(coord);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  }
};
```

SNIPPET NOT TESTED